# Rackspace and Microsoft Azure pricing api

Tags: azure, cloud, rackspace-cloud, rackspace, azure-cloud-services

Is there a public api for getting pricing lists of Rackspace and Microsoft Azure in JSON format?
Have been searching for that but could not find any information.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Pricing as in how much things costs in general, or how tracking of your own bill?

Comment: How much things cost in general. I am creating a portal which will show the complete price list of clouds they provide in general. So I need the costs in general.

Answer (score 0):

For Rackspace, there is not a public API for getting pricing lists in JSON format. You can find a list of the prices for Cloud Servers here if you scroll down to the "pricing" section: http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/servers

You can select a class of OS, service level, and whether you want the prices to be displayed hourly or monthly. Rackspace doesn't offer cloud servers without a support plan, so you'll need to factor that into your calculations. With the DevOps support plan, you'll need to factor in the volume discount for large numbers of servers.

There's also a price calculator here: http://www.rackspace.com/calculator

(Disclaimer: I work at Rackspace.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I want a way to get the pricing information through a program that I am developing. What is best practice in this case?

Answer (score 0):

For Azure, this may help.

I was looking for the same thing and stumble upon this post on stack overflow: [Azure pricing calculator api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42216539/azure-pricing-calculator-api). I was able to generate JSON string using this git hub repo: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/billing-dotnet-ratecard-api.

Hope this helps!